# Обращение к словарю

Tags: python

Как мне обратиться к массиву словаря(result_list) с ключом href, about?
Ну то есть мне надо достать первый элемент массива из словаря, с ключевым словом href и аналогично с другими ключевыми словами

```
# This is a sample Python script.

# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL_Template = "https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs-odesa/?page=2"
r = requests.get(URL_Template)
#print(r.status_code)
#print(r.text)

soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
vacancies_names = soup.find_all('h2', class_='')
vacancies_info = soup.find_all('p', class_='overflow text-muted add-top-sm cut-bottom')
result_list = {'href': [], 'title': [], 'about': []}


try:
    for i in range(2):
        for info in vacancies_info:

            result_list['about'].append(info.text)
        for name in vacancies_names:
            print()
            result_list['title'].append(name.a['title'])
            result_list['href'].append(f"https://www.work.ua{name.a['href']}")




except:
    print(r"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable")

print(result_list)
```

Comment: Первый элемент массива из словаря по ключу href - result_list['href'][0], остальные аналогично

Comment: А как мне вывести построчно мой словарь? 
Ну то есть result_list['href'][0] result_list['tirle'][0] result_list['about'][0]
result_list['href'][1] result_list['tirle'][1] result_list['about'][1]

Comment: это будет уже не словарь, а список: for string in result_list['href'][0]: print(string)